# Table with undefined number of columns

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am creating website with recipes. In every recipe user can add as many ingredients as he want, same with list of steps. And i am not sure how to solve this in database. My idea is to create 3(or more if it will be needed) tables. They would look like this:

Table 1

```
id|recipe_name|etc.
```

Table 2

```
id|recipe_id|ingredient|amount|etc.
```

And table 3 would look similiar to table 2 but instead of ingredients there would be steps.

Is this correct? Or maybe there is another better way to do it.

Comment: You may try posting this question to ... https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One recipe can contain many ingredients and one ingredient can be in many recipes, right? That's a many-to-many relationship between recipes and ingredients. So you might want a recipes table, an ingredients table and a linking table to establish the many-to-many relationship.